# I have multiple bigquery tables list in excel, I want to read the excel and check if all tables exists in bigquery or not using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, google-bigquery, openpyxl

i am currently learning python. I have multiple bigquery tables list in excel, I want to read the excel and check if all tables exists in bigquery or not. and return the results to excel. Could anyone please advise. i am not able to loop through multiple rows and columns.

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound
import numpy


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('file path.json')

project_id = 'creating-data-413804'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

#Reading the excel file 

data = pd.read_excel('file path', usecols=('Dataset','Source Schema', 'Source Table Name', 'Target   BQ Project ID', 'table exist'))

`for col in data.iterrows():

    project_nm = data['Source Schema'][col]
    dataset_nm =data['Dataset'][col]
    table_nm = data['Source Table Name'][col]
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
    dataset = client.dataset(dataset_nm)
    table_ref = dataset.table(table_nm)
    def if_tbl_exists(client, table_ref):
        #from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound
        try:
            client.get_table(table_ref)
            return True
        except NotFound:
            return False`
print(col)
print(if_tbl_exists(client, table_ref))

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('file path.xlsx')  

sheet = book['Sheet1']
if if_tbl_exists(client, table_ref) == True:
    sheet.cell(row=3, column=5).value = 'table exist'
else:
    sheet.cell(row=3, column=5).value = 'table doesnt exist'

book.save('file path.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your sheet is length, I think the for loop makes the process slower. I think getting the distinct datasets and a list of tables in each data set. Now check for table sin the sheet that in the df from bq.

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import openpyxl

# Function Definitions
def get_tables_in_dataset(client, project_id, dataset_id):
    """Fetch tables in a given dataset. Return a list of "projectId.datasetId.tableId" format strings."""
    tables_list = []
    try:
        dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project_id)
        tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset_ref))
        for table in tables:
            tables_list.append(f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table.table_id}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error accessing dataset {dataset_id} in project {project_id}: {e}")
    return tables_list

def create_full_qualified_name(row):
    """Concatenate project, dataset, and table names."""
    return f"{row['Target BQ Project ID']}.{row['Dataset']}.{row['Source Table Name']}"

# Configuration
credentials_path = 'path/to/your/credentials.json'
excel_file_path = 'path/to/your/excel.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'YourSheetName'  # Update with your actual sheet name

# Setup BigQuery Client
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_path)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)

# 1. Read Excel file
df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name)
df1['Qualified Name'] = df1.apply(create_full_qualified_name, axis=1)

# 2. Get distinct projectId.dataset
distinct_datasets = df1['Qualified Name'].apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x.split('.')[:2])).unique()

# 3. Get a list of all tables from BigQuery that are in the list of datasets
all_tables = []
for dataset in distinct_datasets:
    project_id, dataset_id = dataset.split('.')
    tables_in_dataset = get_tables_in_dataset(client, project_id, dataset_id)
    all_tables.extend(tables_in_dataset)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(all_tables, columns=['Qualified Name'])

# Check existence in BQ for each table in df1
df1['Exists in BQ'] = df1['Qualified Name'].isin(df2['Qualified Name'])

# Write the updated df1 back to an Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    
    # Assuming you want to write to a new sheet or replace an existing one
    new_sheet_name = 'Updated'  # Specify your desired sheet name
    if new_sheet_name in writer.sheets:
        # Remove the sheet if it already exists
        del book[new_sheet_name]
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=new_sheet_name, index=False)

# Save the workbook
book.save(excel_file_path)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response @shamiso. I need to update whether tables exist or not to specific column in the same excel.

Comment: @SatyaAnvesh in that case you need add a true/false column. will modify the code.